# How create belonge assocation in models in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, has-many, belongs-to

I use Cakephp framework, and I have problem with my association.
How create belong to association in models in cake php.
When I use belongto and hasMany in my model.

Can I find sample model to view this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simple belongsTo association:

```
<?php
class Profile extends AppModel {
var $name = 'Profile';                
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className'    => 'User',
        'foreignKey'    => 'user_id'
    )
);  
}
?>
```

### Simple hasMany association:

```
<?php
class User extends AppModel {
var $name = 'User';                
var $hasMany = array(
    'Comment' => array(
        'className'     => 'Comment',
        'foreignKey'    => 'user_id',
        'conditions'    => array('Comment.status' => '1'),
        'order'    => 'Comment.created DESC',
        'limit'        => '5',
        'dependent'=> true
    )
);  
}
?>
```

More specific information about associations is in the [CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1039/Associations-Linking-Models-Together).

Answer (score 1):

1. User has Many Photos
2. Photos belongs to User

In User Model :

```
var $hasMany = array(
    'Photo' => array(
        'className' => 'Photo',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id'
);
```

In Photo Model :

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'User' => array(
        'className' => 'User',
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    ),
    'PhotoAlbum' => array(
        'className' => 'PhotoAlbum',
        'foreignKey' => 'photo_album_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => '',
    ))
```

Comment: thanks 
but my main problem when bake Photos controller.
$this->Photos->User->find('all');
but i understand User property is not defined , this true of code is  :
$this->Photos->user->find('all');
means user property should upper case , but this line bake with cake , and my answer is that why cake php framework not recognize true syntax , and what is my solution ?
thanks for all.